# html5 pop-up and functions

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question regarding html5 and an pop-up, and don't know if this is possible to do but I have a promotional video (with its own soundtrack) and a celebration song to celebrate the opening of the site. The aim is to let the pop-up come up right before the user can view the page asking to see the video or listen to song, if they choose video it will be full screen with controllers and able to exit on the controllers, and if it is the song that users choose to be played lopped in the background no controllers while they look through the site, the pop-up should exit after the request is executed, and the pop-up before viewers can view the page should be transparent lets say 75%, and leave the page immobile till request is done, and alternatively have a puton to pass it all on the pop-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into bootstrap's Modal

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

which you can progamatically call using

`$('#myModal').modal('show')` or `$('#myModal').modal('hide')`

or jQuery's Dialog

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

which you can progamiatically call using

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: the site is running bootstarp 3.1 will that conflict with the modal?